# Unexpected network delay when "Base Filtering Engine" service is enabled

Tags: windows, networking

I am running a Jetty web server on a Windows 7 32-bit machine. When "Base Filtering Engine" service is enabled, I see an unexpected 500ms delay after each HTTP response (between the time the server sends a response and the the time the client receives it) even though both client and server run on the same machine. I see the same behavior if client and server run on separate machines.

It's not clear which service is at fault, why, and how to fix it. Any ideas?

(See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=355948 for a related discussion)

Comment: What firewall software do you have installed, if any?

Comment: ESet AntiVirus and Windows firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

1. It turns out that disabling ESET AntiVirus using Setup -> "Temporarily disable Antivirus and antispyware protection" doesn't disable all anti-virus components. When I uninstalled the anti-virus the network latency disappeared.
2. This bug seems to be fixed in the latest version of ESET Antivirus. Upgrading from version 4.0.474.0 to 4.2.71.2 fixed it for us.